# How to add a mobileapp in already exicisting webapp tracking google analytics account

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

**I have a google analytics account for tracking a website but i need the same account for tracking an android application too.How can i use the single account for tracking both mobile app and web app. Please help me.Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to login to your analytics account.

Secondly, Go to your Admin tab of GA account then ceate new property of Mobile App type,select Industry Category & then save/create.

Thirdly,get Track Id/ Property Id of your newly created mobile app property.

Fourthly,download sdk for your mobile platform like Android Sdk/IOS Sdk.

Finally read the documentation for your mobile app platform to send your track data to google analytics.you will get many online resource for this requirement